# Add single line in Actionscript to a flex defined MX Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, charts, flex4

I'm tying to draw a graph of the Accelerometer data, but it is too slow to use the item renderer with an arrayCollection or arrayList.

So, I started using actionscript to draw all the lines and axesusing moveTo and and lineTo, but it's a bit of a pain to do the whole axis and scaling bit.

So can I draw a line chart taking advantages of the component(eg):

```
                    <mx:LineChart id="myChart"
                                  showDataTips="true"
                            width="100%" height="100%">
                ..........
                ..........
                    </mx:LineChart>
```

and in actionscript ADD a new line and add it to the chart?
eg:

```
        myChart.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
        myChart.graphics.lineTo(1,1);
```

My current attempt, shows no line, but no errors.

TIA,

Phil

Comment: using component for that kind of dynamic display/drawing will always be slow. It has to be done drawing to a graphics object for performance sake and maybe even draw and display the entire thing to a bitmapdata. It's a pain? Not really but anyway who said coding had to be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [CartesianDataCanvas](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/CartesianDataCanvas.html) is what you're looking for.

> This class lets you use add graphical elements such as lines,
>   ellipses, and other shapes by using a graphics API. The values that
>   you pass to the graphics API are in data coordinates rather than
>   screen coordinates. You can also add any DisplaObject to the canvas,
>   in the same way that you add children to containers. The drawing
>   region for the canvas is determined by the verticalAxis and
>   horizontalAxis, if they are specified. Otherwise, the canvas uses the
>   default axes of the chart to compute the drawing region.
>
> The data coordinates passed as parameters to the drawing APIs can be
>   actual values of the data coordinate or an object of type
>   CartesianCanvasValue, which can hold a data coordinate value and an
>   offset, in pixels.

Comment: Yes this is what I what searching for. Many thanks for the information.